# Parsing .csv file of integers into a 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, csv, file, parsing

I am trying to parse a .csv file containing integers into a 2d array in C, but my program is not working and I am not sure why.

```
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

(contained above is the .csv file I am trying to parse, its just integers of 1 and 2.)

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 12
#define COLUMNS 12

int main () {

int array [LEVEL_ROWS] [LEVEL_COLUMNS];

FILE *file;

file = fopen("data.csv","r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening file");
    return 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
    {
        if(fscanf(file,"%d,",&array[i][j] )!=1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error reading from file\n");
            fclose(file);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

fclose(file);

for(int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++)
{
    for (int j =0; j < ROWS; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;

}
```

However, my program prints the contents of the .csv file completely wrong and I cannot figure out why

printed output (not the same as actual contents of .csv file):

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

Any help and explanation as to what is wrong? Thank You!

Comment: Your `COLUMNS` and `ROWS` numbers do not correspond to the actual size of the matrix.

Comment: There are 20 columns x 12 rows in the file.

Comment: You don't have `,` after the last number in the file, but the `scanf()` format string expects it after every number.

Comment: You have no `#define` for `LEVEL_ROWS` and `LEVEL_COLUMNS`.

Comment: @Barmar The missing `,` last won't matter though. The extraction will still work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I realized that, but still feel it's bad coding. It just happens to work because there's nothing after it.

Comment: As far as CSV is concerned, the row-end commas make every row but the last have an extra, empty field.  That's not invalid, but it does seem to be semantically incorrect.

Comment: _Side note:_ `fscanf` is slow and the "discussion" over the format to use suggest an alternative might be better. What about `fgets` and looping on `strtol`? Faster and better syntax checking on input. Also, the number of elements in the row can be checked against the number of expected elements. Since the data is _only_ `2` or `1`, even looping on `fgetc` might be better.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes indeed. I was wondering if I should go with `fgets` in my answer but thought that would be too much of a rewrite.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was being kind in my comment: I _hate_ `*scanf` ;-) Please feel free to show the "correct" way to do this ;-) I've seen answers/replies to other questions that contort/torture the format arg to work. Or, they abandon `fscanf` in favor of `fgets` et. al. I've seen more comments recently that disparage the lineage of `*scanf`, so I think that consensus is growing.

Comment: @CraigEstey Brootal :-) It's bedtime now but I'll probably add an `fgets` alternative after work tomorrow.

Comment: This is an invalid csv file. All records **must have** the same number of separators. You can check it again any on-line free csv-validator. [Refer to RFC-4180 section 2 item 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). It is not in fact an RFC since _csv_ precedes IETF and W3C by decades.

Comment: @arfneto It is not. Just because you have an idea, it doesn't make it an ultimate truth. Procaliming it is the ultimate truth just hurts.

Comment: Sorry. It was never my intention. Nothing of this is my idea. This is just what is in a RFC, older than the existence of RFC: 4180 is just a collection of practices there were not also my idea. The first time I wrote something to parse a csv was on an PDP-11/45 under RSX-11M so there goes some years. I never sat down with any company to _"define"_ a format. Most of the time I just received such a file, or create one to send out, with no control on the other side. There was a standard and it was resumed on RFC-4180 decades after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `#define COLUMNS 12` doesn't match the number of columns in the file. There are 20 columns in the file.
- `LEVEL_ROWS` and `LEVEL_COLUMNS` are not defined at all.
- If you want to take advantage of the intrinsic [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) storage in C, don't read column values into the natural row extent of your array. You've defined the array `int array [LEVEL_ROWS][LEVEL_COLUMNS];`, but you read column values into the rows and vice versa.
- The "missing" `,` at the end of the last row is not a problem right now but it looks unfinished. Better be consistent. I would remove the last comma in every row (or possibly add one to all of them).

If you then define `COLUMNS` to be 20 and swap row and column reading (and printing), it'll work out fine. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS (12)
#define COLUMNS (20)

int main(void) {
    const char* filename = "data.csv";

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        perror(filename);
        return 1;
    }

    int array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            if(fscanf(file, "%d,", &array[row][col]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error reading from file\n");
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: The missing comma is in fact a problem, this is an invalid csv file. csv files are tabula

Comment: @arfneto "csv" (_comma separated values_) files is used for _many_ types of files. Originally for comma separated values, but there are no real restrictions on what you call a "csv" file. There are _tons_ of different csv formats.

Comment: consider tons of online free validators, the RFC4180, and massive data sources like [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/)

Comment: @arfneto The _"MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values"_ does not apply to every place where csv is used. csv existed long before  RFC4180 and RFC4180 does not cover all the csv formats that are in use worldwide.

Comment: Well, it is ok to call it a csv, just by having some fields and some separators, after all. But if you want to distribute your _csv_ it may be better to follow the simple rules. Try a dataset from kaggle under any validator, try this question's one...

Comment: @arfneto It wouldn't be too hard to write the csv specification for the file format OP has and then to write a seriously proper validator for it though. I'm not sure what good a dataset from kaggle would do here?

Comment: any of these datasets would serve just as examples: csv files are collections of records, records have fields, separators define fields, Each record has exactly the same number of fields, not some with 20 and some with 21 like in the OP example. csv files are in trend know because of model training in AI. And guess what? the position and presence of each field, here called attribute, is essential. As you wrote, _"better be consistent"_ as each non-compliant record must be discarded.

Comment: @arfneto I think you are trying to put rules to what a "csv" file is that isn't globally agreed upon.  There are many formats where "a record" is allowed to be broken up into several lines, just because it becomes easier to communicate it in clear-text with humans. A record in OPs file consists of 240 `1` or `2`s with a comma between each. Newlines are allowed to be inserted for presentation purposes but should otherwise be ignored. Each record describes a 12x20 matrix, row-major order.

Comment: That's ok. If you follow the simple rules from the 70's you can import your file into ORACLE, into Google Cloud products, into any database, EXCEL, Avery labels software since the 80's, Word mailing-labels and so on. hundred-thousand lines datasets from public or private datasets et al, can also be imported by your code.  Or you can choose to give it some freedom, considering that any text is a csv file, you can have as many separators as you want, if any. And try your luck.

Comment: @arfneto Exactly. Just as long as the specific csv format is specified, anything goes. And since a parser for OPs specific csv format only needs to handle that very format, it can be optimized for that purpose only.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that many times you do not wrote the csv file you are trying to read. And many _other_ times you do not know what program will be used to import a _csv_ file with the flavor you like, the way you wrote. csv is a thing form the 70's. A tabular MxN file. Do as I said, and you will read csv files from the 70's, and your file can be read by the Avery Labels sw that came in 5,25"diskettes in the early 90's. Or do not. There is no _specific format to be specified_  if you can not create the consumer or the producer program, or just have a csv  you need to read  _now_.

Comment: @arfneto _"Do as I said, and you will read csv files from the 70's..."_ - You are addressing the wrong person here I think and I think you exaggerate the importance of having OPs csv parseable by every parser on the planet - and not even those old parsers will agree 100% about what a csv is. I think I actually wrote my first parser '79 or '80. Of course, then we had tapes and 8" floppys if we were lucky. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

is not a valid csv file. csv files must have the same number of fields in every record. Since the separators defines the fields, each line must have the same number of separators, even if there are no data for some fields. Fields are optional but their positions not.

This is a valid csv file:

```
, , , , 
1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,
```

This is also valid

```
    , , ,
    , , ,
    , , ,
```

#### more definitions on csv format

- the first line of a csv file can have what is called a header-line, and lists the name of each field. It was used to produce mailing labels in the 90's, it is used to supply the column names for a database table to be imported in SQL. This is the example with a header line:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,quantity
,,,, 
1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,
```

See this file imported into Sheets from Google

[image]

Note how the absent fields are preserved as blank cells. This is why every record (line) must have the same number of separators

- the last record can or can not have a newline at the end
- spaces are considered part of a field
- fields can be "quoted" and this means that you can use some delimiter to enclose a field that has a delimiter inside, like commas in a comma separated csv file. Example below:

```
field1,"Unit Price",field3,field4,quantity
,,,, 
1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,
```

See this imported into Excel from  Microsoft

[image]

And note that spaces are preserved in `B1` and `B3` due to quotes.

This format is around since the 70's and is present in many areas. Since it is an interchange format, many times you have just the file to read, other times you have to write a file to sent someone to, and you have no control of one side or the other.
*csv* files are imported into any database, into MS-Office programs, into Google Cloud products, label-printing software form the 90's ofen came with a program in 5,25" floppy disk to produce labels based on a csv-file.
And in the last years csv get some more traction due to AI, since almost all dataset can be downloaded as a *csv* file, and parsing a *csv* to prepare data before training the model is very convenient in `C`. Python also has a module *csv*.

Here is an example on how to import a csv file into a MySQL database, from the documentation

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The last line is an instruction to ignore the header line. This is the case when the column names in the database are already set. The rest is self-explanatory.
We can see the same details I wrote before, about the separator, line terminator, header line and field quoting.

There is no formal definition of a csv format because when it was created there was no such thing as IETF or W3C. IETF produced something like an RFC, the [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) that tries to give some definitions, but it is too late, since these files are everywhere since the 70's and programs import these files since then.
And since then the files are as I wrote above: a possibly giant MxN table. M records with exactly N fields marked by N-1 identical separators, one per line.

#### importing a *csv* file with any number of fields and records

I will show an example of importing such a thing. I will not implement header line parsing and quoting, since it makes no difference and it is already a long and maybe boring post.

This example reads a *csv* file with *any* number of records with any number of fields. Can be easily changed. Memory is allocated in blocks as big as the user want (and the machine memory permits). Memory size can grow on demand and is automatic in the example. Full code and output are at the end.

The usual approach, and the one here used, is to scan the first line of the file and just count the number of fields.

This function does just this:

```
size_t csv_get_n_fields(const char* file, const char delim)
{
    FILE* fl = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fl == NULL) return 0;
    char   line[250];
    size_t n_fields = 0;
    char*  p        = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fl);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fl);
        return 0;
    }
    while (*p != 0)
        if (delim == *p++) ++n_fields;
    fclose(fl);
    return 1 + n_fields;
}
```

Knowing the number of fields we can proceed to read all records. But we need an abstraction, a model.

#### an abstraction for a CSV file of `int` values

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t n_fields;     // columns
    size_t n_records;    // rows
    size_t max_records;  // limit
    int**  array;
} CSV_i;
```

Each line of the array holds a valid record of the csv file. Line 0 of the file is array[0] and is an array of `int` with the fields, no surprise here. The number of fields was determined by the function above, so we can just scan the file and upload the data.

#### 4 operations on `CSV_i`

```
CSV_i* csv_create(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim);
CSV_i* csv_destroy(CSV_i* del);
CSV_i* csv_read(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim);
int csv_show(CSV_i* csv, const char* msg);
```

No surprise here: just the bare minimun. In `csv_create()` `block` is the unit of allocation, in bytes. The example uses 64K. Could be on the command line, for sure.

#### the `main` code in the example

```
#define BLK_SIZE (size_t)(64 * 1024)
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    const char* def_file = "input5.csv";
    char        f_name[200] = {0};
    if (argc < 2)
        strcpy(f_name, def_file);
    else
        strcpy(f_name, argv[1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "File is '%s'\n", f_name);
    CSV_i* my_csv =
        csv_read(f_name, BLK_SIZE, DELIM_COMMA);
    char msg[80] = {0};
    sprintf(msg, "test_file for %zu bytes:   ", BLK_SIZE);
    csv_show(my_csv, msg);
    csv_destroy(my_csv);
    return 0;
}
```

Any csv file can be read this way. The user can input the file name in a command line. The struct is allocated and extended as needed.

#### running the example with a few files

```
Stack Overflow > type input5.csv
, , , ,
1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,

Stack Overflow > p input5.csv
File is 'input5.csv'
csv has 5 fields
test_file for 65536 bytes:   array [3276,5] (in use: 3/3276 records)

0 0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 5
0 6 7 8 0

Stack Overflow > type input4.csv
,999,,
15,16,17,18
1,2,3,4
10,,,11

Stack Overflow > p input4.csv
File is 'input4.csv'
csv has 4 fields
test_file for 65536 bytes:   array [4096,4] (in use: 4/4096 records)

0 999 0 0
15 16 17 18
1 2 3 4
10 0 0 11

[end]

Stack Overflow >

Stack Overflow > type input.csv
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
Stack Overflow > p input.csv
File is 'input.csv'
csv has 20 fields
test_file for 65536 bytes:   array [819,20] (in use: 13/819 records)

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[end]

Stack Overflow >
```

Input lines that does not have the required number of fields are just ignored.

### about the code

#### readind the records

The main logic is in  `csv_read` as below

```
CSV_i* csv_read(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim)
{
    CSV_i* one = csv_create(file, block, delim);
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    FILE* fl = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fl == NULL)
    {
        csv_destroy(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    // read all records
    do {
        // read all fields
        char  line[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = {0};
        char* p_in = fgets(line, (int)sizeof(line), fl);
        if (p_in == NULL) break;  // read line by line
        size_t res = csv_get_line(line, one, delim);
        if (res == 0) ++one->n_records;
        if (one->n_records == one->max_records)
        {
            if (csv_extend(one) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "no more space on array\n");
                fclose(fl);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (1);
    fclose(fl);
    ++one->n_records;
    return one;
}
```

- The file is consumed by `fgets` calls
- The CSV representation in memory is created with a size based on a block size that is a parameter of the function. The function then calculates the maximum number of records that can fit in such size.
- the structure is linearly extended as needed, in this example in 64K blocks. It can be changed for a lesser value in order to see how the extension works: messages are sent to `stderr` at these extension points.

#### reading the fields

```
size_t csv_get_line(
    const char* line, CSV_i* one, const char delim)
```

this function gets a line and parse it into the *csv*. It could use `sscanf` but instead a very simple 2-states [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is used. It is easier to test and change, e.g. if we decide to add quoting for fields.

Being a separate function it is easier to test with special lines of input, outside of the *csv* thing.

#### Full `C` code for the example

```
// 64K buffer at start
#define BLK_SIZE (size_t)(64 * 1024)
// standard delimiter
#define DELIM_COMMA ','
// max 4-digits fields, for testing
#define MAX_FIELD_SIZE 4
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 250

#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t n_fields;     // columns
    size_t n_records;    // rows
    size_t max_records;  // limit
    int**  array;
} CSV_i;

CSV_i* csv_create(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim);
CSV_i* csv_destroy(CSV_i* del);
CSV_i* csv_read(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim);
int csv_show(CSV_i* csv, const char* msg);

// helpers
int    csv_extend(CSV_i* csv);
size_t csv_get_n_fields(const char* file, const char delim);
size_t csv_get_line(
    const char* line, CSV_i* csv, const char delim);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    const char* def_file = "input5.csv";
    char        f_name[200] = {0};
    if (argc < 2)
        strcpy(f_name, def_file);
    else
        strcpy(f_name, argv[1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "File is '%s'\n", f_name);
    CSV_i* my_csv =
        csv_read(f_name, BLK_SIZE, DELIM_COMMA);
    char msg[80] = {0};
    sprintf(msg, "test_file for %zu bytes:   ", BLK_SIZE);
    csv_show(my_csv, msg);
    csv_destroy(my_csv);
    return 0;
}

CSV_i* csv_create(
    const char* file, size_t block, char delim)
{
    if (file == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t n_fields = csv_get_n_fields(file, delim);
    if (n_fields == 0) return NULL;
    printf("csv has %zu fields\n", n_fields);
    CSV_i* one = (CSV_i*)malloc(sizeof(CSV_i));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->n_fields    = n_fields;
    one->n_records   = 0;  // empty
    one->max_records = block / n_fields / sizeof(int);
    if (one->max_records < 1) one->max_records = 1;
    // malloc the lines
    one->array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * one->max_records);
    if (one->array == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    // build the columns inside lines
    size_t row = 0;
    for (; row < one->max_records; row += 1)
    {
        one->array[row] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_fields);
        if (one->array[row] == NULL) break;
    }
    if (row == one->max_records) return one;
    // error: undo everything
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i += 1) free(one->array[i]);
    free(one->array);
    free(one);
    return NULL;
}

CSV_i* csv_destroy(CSV_i* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < del->max_records; row += 1)
        free(del->array[row]);
    free(del->array);
    free(del);
    return NULL;
}

int csv_extend(CSV_i* csv)
{
    if (csv == NULL) return -1;
    size_t new_size = csv->max_records + csv->max_records;
    int**  new_block =
        realloc(csv->array, sizeof(int*) * new_size);
    if (new_block == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not extend size from %zu to "
            "%zu\n",
            csv->max_records, new_size);
        return -2;
    }
    // build the columns inside lines
    csv->array = new_block;
    size_t row = csv->max_records;
    for (; row < new_size; row += 1)
    {
        csv->array[row] =
            malloc(sizeof(int) * csv->n_fields);
        if (csv->array[row] == NULL) break;
    }
    if (row == new_size)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "EXTEND: size went from %zu to "
            "%zu\n",
            csv->max_records, new_size);
        csv->max_records = new_size;
        csv->array       = new_block;
        return 0;  // ok
    }
    // error: undo everything in reverse
    for (size_t i = csv->max_records; i < row; i += 1)
        free(csv->array[i]);
    new_size = csv->max_records / 2;
    new_block =
        realloc(csv->array, sizeof(int*) * new_size);
    if (new_block == NULL)
    {  // this should never fail
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not trim size from %zu to "
            "%zu\n",
            new_size, csv->max_records);
        return -3;
    }
    csv->array = new_block;  // reset
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "EXTEND: failed: size reset from %zu to "
        "%zu\n",
        csv->max_records, new_size);
    csv->max_records = new_size;
    return 0;
}

CSV_i* csv_read(
    const char* file, size_t block, const char delim)
{
    CSV_i* one = csv_create(file, block, delim);
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    FILE* fl = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fl == NULL)
    {
        csv_destroy(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    // read all records
    do {
        // read all fields
        char  line[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = {0};
        char* p_in = fgets(line, (int)sizeof(line), fl);
        if (p_in == NULL) break;  // read line by line
        size_t res = csv_get_line(line, one, delim);
        if (res == 0) ++one->n_records;
        if (one->n_records == one->max_records)
        {
            if (csv_extend(one) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "no more space on array\n");
                fclose(fl);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (1);
    fclose(fl);
    ++one->n_records;
    return one;
}

int csv_show(CSV_i* csv, const char* msg)
{
    if (csv == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "array [%zu,%zu] (in use: %zu/%zu records)\n\n",
        csv->max_records, csv->n_fields, csv->n_records - 1,
        csv->max_records);
    for (size_t row = 0; row < csv->n_records - 1; row += 1)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < csv->n_fields; col += 1)
            printf("%d ", csv->array[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n[end]\n");
    return 0;
}

size_t csv_get_n_fields(const char* file, const char delim)
{
    FILE* fl = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fl == NULL) return 0;
    char   line[250];
    size_t n_fields = 0;
    char*  p        = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fl);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fl);
        return 0;
    }
    while (*p != 0)
        if (delim == *p++) ++n_fields;
    fclose(fl);
    return 1 + n_fields;
}

#define ST_INFIELD 0
#define ST_OVERFLOW 1

size_t csv_get_line(
    const char* line, CSV_i* one, const char delim)
{
    char        field[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = {0};
    const char* p_in                 = line;
    char*       p_out = field;  // pointer to field
    size_t      col   = 0;
    for (; col < one->n_fields; col += 1)
    {
        char state    = ST_INFIELD;
        char read_one = 0;
        while (!read_one)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case ST_INFIELD:
                    if (*p_in == 0)
                    {  // eol
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        read_one = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (*p_in == delim)
                    {
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        p_out = field;  // reset field ptr
                        ++p_in;
                        read_one = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (*p_in == '\n')
                    {  // must be the last field
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        p_out = field;  // reset field ptr
                        ++p_in;
                        read_one = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((p_out - field) == MAX_FIELD_SIZE)
                    {
                        state = ST_OVERFLOW;
                        ++p_in;
                        break;
                    }
                    *p_out++ = *p_in++;  // copy this one
                    break;
                case ST_OVERFLOW:
                    if (*p_in == 0)
                    {  // eol
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        p_out = field;  // reset field ptr
                        read_one = 1;
                        state    = ST_INFIELD;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (*p_in == delim)
                    {
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        p_out = field;  // reset field ptr
                        state = ST_INFIELD;
                        ++p_in;
                        read_one = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (*p_in == '\n')
                    {
                        *p_out = 0;
                        one->array[one->n_records][col] =
                            atoi(field);
                        p_out = field;  // reset field ptr
                        state = ST_INFIELD;
                        read_one = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    ++p_in;  // ignore
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }  // while()
        if (*p_in == 0) break;
    }  // for
    if (col == one->n_fields - 1) return 0;
    return col;
}
```